# I want to use script chmod automatically every minute this is my script?

Tags: linux, cron

I want to use script chmod automatically every minute this is my script

```
# vim /home/crontab/chmod.sh
#!/bin/sh
chmod +x /home
```

And this is my crontab

```
# crontab -e 
*/5 * * * * /home/crontab/chmod.sh
```

What's wrong on my script and my crontab ?

Comment: You haven't said what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.  We can't read your mind. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank's jim i want to use script for chmod automatically every minute :)

Comment: You still haven't told us what is actually happening that is "wrong".

Comment: @JimGarrison Im sorry if my question doesnot clear, i have mirroring server on my office i want when my server master off i want my app in Slave automaticaly on but when i chek my app on the slave permission to my app, well i use chmod manualy but  only for a moment

Comment: Please provide the aim or the goal that you want to achieve inside the question so, anybody who tries to answer this question instantly understands the meaning of the question. Also, provide the error message or unexpected results that you get. However, this is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Cron expression for every minute:-

```
*/1 * * * * <ur command>
```

And to execute your script first do chmod on your script.

```
chmod +x /home/crontab/chmod.sh
```

And don't forget to add a **blank new line** in the **end** of your crontab as well as Shell script.